# 'MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN' does not match the expected pairing token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, abp

I have deployed application as a Azure Web App. Everything Works fine with the get http calls but when i make a http post, put call from my front end app i receive this error "MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN' does not match the expected pairing token".

Hosting: Azure Web Apps
Backend: Aspnet Core 5
Front End: Angular App
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show your code in  startup.cs and program.cs , and pls hide sensitive info.

Comment: Hi @JasonPan Have edited the question with screenshots. Thank you!

Comment: Try to add this line   `app.UseAuthentication();`  in you startup.cs file.

Comment: I tried that but doesn't work.